# SSL Certification with nginx and tomcat

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, java, openssl

I have an nginx server, which can forward request from subdomains of `ropi.io`. I want to secure the connection with SSL, so I generated a certificate, called `ropi.pem` and added it as both the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` since I generated it with OpenSSL, where both the key out, and the certificate was this single file.

It works fine when browser clients want to connect to the server, but in some cases, I do need to connect with a Java client. The problem is that Java Keystore cannot import `.pem` files, so I - with OpenSSL again - converted it to `.der` format, which the Keystore accepts.

This, however, does not fix the problem, where I still cannot connect to the server from a Java client, since I get the same `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` exception.

Is there a mutual format that both Nginx, and Java Keystore can use and works for domains, CN, etc. as well?

I'm a noob, when it comes to SSL Certification, but I'm determined to learn, so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I had to create a certificate from the key file, with the domain I want clearly stated (it'll tell where it's needed when generating).

I used the `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -key ../nginx/ropi.pem -out certificate.crt` command, made sure the right files are added to the right Keystore, and I was all set